# handling sequential tasks with purrr

Tags: r, purrr, seurat

I would like to take list of objects and build a single object out of all of them.  The actual use case is to combine multiple Seurat Objects into a single object.  Currently I use a for loop, however, I was curious if I could use purrr::map.  To make the problem simpler, lets just concatenate a part of a list.  Try not to get too cute with the result because I the true problem is more difficult (a more complex function).

```
w1 = list(a="first",b="This")
w2 = list(a="second",b="is")
w3 = list(a="third",b="the")
w4 = list(a="fourth",b="desired results")
```

The desired results would be an "This is the desired results".

```
list(w1,w2,w3,w4) %>% map(paste,.$b," ")
```

gives

> [[1]] [1] "This  "
>
> [[2]] [1] "is  "
>
> [[3]] [1] "the  "
>
> [[4]] [1] "desired result  "

I would like to save the results of the previous iteration and add it as a parameter to the function.

essentially I would like to replace the following line with a functional.

```
y=NULL;for (x in list(w1,w2,w3,w4)){ y=ifelse(is.null(y),x$b,paste0(y," ",x$b))}
#y
#"This is the desired result"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(purrr)

list(w1, w2, w3, w4) %>% 
  accumulate(~paste(.x, .y[2][[1]]), .init = '') %>% 
  tail(1) %>% 
  substr(2, nchar(.))

# [1] "This is the desired results"
```

Comment: This is great, actually it pointed me to reduce, which is even better.  I settled on list(w1, w2, w3, w4) %>% reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(nchar(x)==0,y$b,paste0(x," ",y$b)) ,.init = '')  Thank you Ryan.  Will accept the answer when I can.

Answer (score 4):

With `do.call` and `lapply` in Base R:

```
do.call(paste, lapply(list(w1,w2,w3,w4), `[[`, "b"))

# [1] "This is the desired results"
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend this using `purrr`

```
list(w1,w2,w3,w4) %>% 
  map_chr("b") %>% 
  paste(collapse=" ")
```

We can pass a string to `map()` to return just that named element, and since we are expecting only character values, we can use `map_chr` to get just a vector of character values rather than a list. Finally just pipe that to `paste(collapse=)` to turn it into just one string.

But more generally if you want to collapse incrementally, you can use `reduce`.

```
list(w1, w2, w3, w4) %>% 
  map_chr("b") %>%
  reduce(~paste(.x, .y))
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Flick. reduce was the function that I needed.  Thanks!